# BLE 5 data rates supported by iOS and Android

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

1. What are the different BLE 5 data rates supported by latest version of iOS and Android?
2. Also, what are the different connection parameters supported by
   these two platforms?
3. Is there a publicly available documentation which specifies this information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new PHYs are supported as long as the Bluetooth chip in the phone/tablet supports them. You can initiate an update of the symbol rate to 2 MBit/s from the remote device as a workaround if you use an old Android version which doesn't have an API to update the PHY. The connection parameters are not affected by the PHY selection (I think?) so all old restrictions should still apply.

Android API level 26 has added new methods which you can find in the documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html.